# Reduce multiple blank lines to single (Pythonically)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How can I reduce multiple blank lines in a text file to a single line at each occurrence?

I have read the entire file into a string, because I want to do some replacement across line endings.

```
with open(sourceFileName, 'rt') as sourceFile:
    sourceFileContents = sourceFile.read()
```

This doesn't seem to work

```
while '\n\n\n' in sourceFileContents:
    sourceFileContents = sourceFileContents.replace('\n\n\n', '\n\n')
```

and nor does this

```
sourceFileContents = re.sub('\n\n\n+', '\n\n', sourceFileContents)
```

It's easy enough to strip them all, but I want to reduce multiple blank lines to a single one, each time I encounter them.

I feel that I'm close, but just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a reach, but perhaps some of the lines aren't completely blank (i.e. they have only whitespace characters that give the appearance of blankness). You could try removing all possible whitespace between newlines.

```
re.sub(r'(\n\s*)+\n+', '\n\n', sourceFileContents)
```

**Edit:** realized the second '+' was superfluous, as the \s* will catch newlines between the first and last. We just want to make sure the last character is definitely a newline so we don't remove leading whitespace from a line with other content.

```
re.sub(r'(\n\s*)+\n', '\n\n', sourceFileContents)
```

**Edit 2**

```
re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n\n', sourceFileContents)
```

Should be an even simpler solution. We really just want to a catch any possible space (which includes intermediate newlines) between our two anchor newlines that will make the single blank line and collapse it down to just the two newlines.

Comment: will that only remove the space, or also reduce the multiple blank lines?

Comment: Should do both, at least from my simple test. It should not remove whitespace from the beginning of a line with other content.

Answer (score 10):

Your code works for me. Maybe there is a chance of carriage return `\r` would be present.

```
re.sub(r'[\r\n][\r\n]{2,}', '\n\n', sourceFileContents)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use just str methods split and join:

```
text = "some text\n\n\n\nanother line\n\n"
print("\n".join(item for item in text.split('\n') if item))
```

Answer (score 4):

If the lines are completely empty, you can use regex [*positive lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to replace them with single lines:

```
sourceFileContents = re.sub(r'\n+(?=\n)', '\n', sourceFileContents)
```

[image: regex positive lookahead]

Answer (score 4):

Very simple approach using `re` module

```
import re

text = 'Abc\n\n\ndef\nGhijk\n\nLmnop'
text = re.sub('[\n]+', '\n', text) # Replacing one or more consecutive newlines with single \n
```

## Result:

'**Abc**\n**def**\n**Ghijk**\n**Lmnop**'

Answer (score 2):

If you replace your read statement with the following, then you don't have to worry about whitespace or carriage returns:

```
with open(sourceFileName, 'rt') as sourceFile:
    sourceFileContents = ''.join([l.rstrip() + '\n' for l in sourceFile])
```

After doing this, both of your methods you tried in the OP work.

**OR**

Just write it out in a simple loop.

```
with open(sourceFileName, 'rt') as sourceFile:
    lines = ['']
    for line in (l.rstrip() for l in sourceFile):
        if line != '' or lines[-1] != '\n':
            lines.append(line + '\n')
    sourceFileContents = "".join(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess another option which is longer, but maybe prettier?

```
with open(sourceFileName, 'rt') as sourceFile:
    last_line = None
    lines = []
    for line in sourceFile:
         # if you want to skip lines with only whitespace, you could add something like:
            # line = line.lstrip(" \t")
        if last_line != "\n":
            lines.append(line)
        last_line = line
 contents = "".join(lines)
```

I was trying to find some clever generator function way of writing this, but it's been a long week so I can't.

Code untested, but I think it should work?

(edit: One upside is I removed the need for regular expressions which fixes the "now you have two problems" problem :) )

(another edit based on Marc Chiesa's suggestion of lingering whitespace)

Comment: You could do lines[-1] instead of last line. Also just doing line.rstrip() would strip all whitespace from the end of a line (which is a good thing to do any way) and return an empty string.

Comment: Lol - now you have two problems :-)   For those who don't recognize the quote, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems

Comment: @cdhagmann - wouldn't work in this case - I always want to see the last line from the file, not the last line I've added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

If decoding from unicode, watch out for non-breaking spaces which show up in cat -vet as **M-BM-**:

```
sourceFileContents = sourceFile.read()
sourceFileContents = re.sub(r'\n(\s*\n)+','\n\n',sourceFileContents.replace("\xc2\xa0"," "))
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who can't do regex like me, if the code to process is python:

```py
import autopep8

autopep8.fixcode('your_code')
```

Another quick solution, just in case your code isn't Python:

```py
for x in range(100):
    content.replace("  ", " ")   # reduce the number of multiple whitespaces

# then
for x in range(20):
    content.replace("\n\n", "\n")   # reduce the number of multiple white lines
```

Note that if you have more than 100 consecutive whitespaces or 20 consecutive new lines, you'll want to increase the repetition times.