# Limiting number of <br> tags generated via Django's linbreaksbr filter

Tags: django, django-template-filters

For a user-generated content forum built via Django, I'm contemplating using the filter `linkbreaksbr` when displaying content in the template. One problem is that it converts **all** user-entered new lines into `<br>` tags. That opens it to abuse (e.g. posts where the submitter enters numerous new lines between sentences).

Whenever there are multiple new line characters, I'd prefer the result to be a single `<br>`.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality via Django's `linebreaksbr`? If not, what would be a way to override this and create my required functionality? It would be nice to get an illustrative answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you that reduce number of new lines at save time, so in `MyModel.save` or in your form validation simply replace multiple new lines with one

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901452/reduce-multiple-blank-lines-to-single-pythonically) question

Comment: That's actually a cool idea. I think I'll go for form validation. Btw, prior to reading your answer, I was thinking I'd fall back to the `linebreaks` filter and override the `p` tag to have 0 `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`. It approximates the same effect I'm looking for - but overriding `p` is quite hacky. Thanks again!