# How to remove leading and trailing whitespace from each line in an MD file while preserving empty lines?

Tags: python, markdown

I have Markdown text stored in a variable which I later write to an `MD` file. The Markdown contains trailing and leading whitespace and lines with only whitespace. I have tried to remove the whitespace from the variable as well as from the `MD` file but to no avail.

Please note:

- The headline ## contains a leading whitespace
- Paragraph [1] contains a leading whitespace
- The second line after paragraph [2] is not empty but contains two whitespaces (might not be visible in code block)
- Paragraph [a.] is followed by two trailing spaces

```py
markdown = ''' ## This is a headline

 [1] This is the first paragraph

[2] This is the second paragraph

  
a. This is the third paragraph;  
b. This is the fourth paragraph.'''

with open("output.md", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write(markdown)
```

Ideally, `output.md` would look like this:

```
## This is a headline

[1] This is the first paragraph

[2] This is the second paragraph

a. This is the third paragraph;
b. This is the fourth paragraph.
```

Edit: Applying the accepted answer of @Mortz to the real source, I realised that Markdown uses two spaces for the `<br>` tag. The removal of trailing spaces is therefore not needed in this case. The leading spaces can be removed with: `clean_markdown = '\n'.join(_.lstrip() for _ in markdown.split('\n'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split on the line break character  - `'\n'` and rejoin all the entries with the leading and trailing spaces stripped -

```
print(repr(markdown))
#' ## This is a headline\n\n [1] This is the first paragraph\n \n [2] This is the second paragraph\n \n   \n   a. This is the third paragraph;  \n   b. This is the fourth paragraph.'

clean_markdown = '\n'.join(_.strip() for _ in markdown.split('\n'))

print(repr(clean_markdown))
#'## This is a headline\n\n[1] This is the first paragraph\n\n[2] This is the second paragraph\n\n\na. This is the third paragraph;\nb. This is the fourth paragraph.'
```

And write this `clean_markdown` to your file

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer; this removes all trailing and leading whitespace and answers the main part of the question. Could the removal of double empty lines also be implemented in this solution? Alternatively I will handle it once the file has been written out (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901452/reduce-multiple-blank-lines-to-single-pythonically)).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by "double empty lines". Do you mean you want to replace two or more consecutive empty lines with exactly one empty line?

Comment: Sorry if my phrasing was inaccurate. Exactly, emptly lines of two or more should be replaced with exactly one. Applied to the example, the two lines between paragraph [2] and [a.] should be reduced to one line.