# Python addind black lines when writting out text and cannot get rid of them

Tags: python-3.x, api, text, filewriter

I am in the process of writting a python script that downloads a copy of quarantined emails from our gateway. The emails are in .eml format ( text ) so was thinking this would be easy but the resulting file does not open in Outlook properly due to the newlines added .

Here is the download/write function :

```
def download_message(api_key,endpoint,id):
    endpoint = endpoint + "email/" + id
    headers = {
    'x-fireeye-api-key': api_key,
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'}
    data = {}
    r = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    if "not found in quarantine." in r.text:
        print("Not found in Quarantine")
    else:
        filename = base_directory + id + ".eml"
        f = open(filename,"w")
        f.write(r.text)
        f.close()
        print("Written : " + id + ".eml" + " to disk")
```

Here is an example of the output file when opened in a text editor
[image: api_file_text_editor]

When opened in Outlook this is what it looks like :

[image: opened_in_outlook]

If i manually remove all those blank lines ( regex :  ^\n ) and save the file it works as expected.
I have tried quite a few ways of removing those blank lines including strip , rstrip , re.sub and nothing seems to have worked.

If it helps what i was trying to do was create a new variable to hold the "modified" text and then pass that to the write function.
would have looked something like this ( sorry i have tried loads of variations which i have saved but i think you will get the point )

```
filedata = r.body.strip("\n") or filedata = re.sub('^\n' , "" , r.text)
...
f.write(filedata)
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `f = open(filename,"w")` & `f.write(f.text)` : so `f` is a filehandle that you open with "w" (wich will truncate if existing, else create) - so it is an empty file .... and then you access its .text property and write that into it? What ever should come from this?

Comment: Read up on contexthandlers for file handling;    `with open(fileName, "w") as f: .... ` - it is the recommed way to make sure your file handle is closed even if exceptions happen. Also: [mre] - this example is nothing we can run/replicate your problem with.

Comment: dam really sorry but made a mistake in the code above as i was copying it over. Should be   f.write( r.text )

Comment: In that case you are getting data via request.get(..).text - whatever is provided you write into your file. Inspect it - it may simply contain those additional newlines. You can always strip them if needed by postprocessing - f.e. [Reduce multiple blank lines to single (Pythonically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901452/reduce-multiple-blank-lines-to-single-pythonically)